# Plug Parser Unsupported Media Type error for :delete requests in Exunit tests

Tags: elixir

In my tests, I'm hitting the router with json for each route, and only json is accepted by Plug.parser.  This works fine, except for tests using the delete method, which always fail with Unsupported content type: multipart/mixed.  I'm sending an empty body with the delete request with my application/json as content-type in the headers, but I think the _method parameter is causing it to be rejected as wrong content type- although this does not happen with put method which should require _method to be added to request body also.

```
test "inactivate" do
  {id, token} = register
  response = Myapp.Router.call(conn(:delete, "/api/manager/tenants/" <> id, 
    [], headers: [{"content-type", "application/json"}, {"token", token}] ) |> Plug.Conn.fetch_params(), @opts)
  assert response.status == 200
end
```

when hitting the same delete routes with httprequester, they work fine and are not stopped by plug parser.  Does Router.call handle http requests differently in tests?

Comment: Phoenix now ships with a `MyApp.ConnCase`. You should use that when running Controller tests. It provides conveniences for testing Controllers.

Comment: You are not sending an empty body. An empty list represents empty *parameters*. You can try setting it to an empty string `""` but that will likely  fail because it is not valid JSON. Or send "{}" or do not send anything (nil).

Comment: This worked.  I had to send nil as the body.

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix now ships with a `MyApp.ConnCase`. You should use that when running Controller tests. It provides conveniences for testing Controllers. It goes through the plug stack in both Endpoint and Router for you every time you call a http method like `get conn(), "/"`.

In your case, a delete request using `MyApp.ConnCase` would be like:

```
conn = conn()
  |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
  |> put_req_header("token", token)
  |> delete("/api/manager/tenants/" <> id, params)

assert response(conn, 200)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm still working with v0.10, and a large codebase I would need to wade through to upgrade, but yeah this makes test much easier!!